# JavaScript download progress in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, progress-bar, loader

I have an Android app which is mostly in webview. In webview I'm mostly working with JavaScript. In my JavaScript file I reference a file from a server and I need to show the download progress of the file. I wanted to know if there are any ways to show the download progress in JavaScript in webview.

Thanks very much .

Comment: Is your app fully in java script?

Comment: @sadasidha no it launches with Java and opens an html files which has has the javascript file

Comment: You can do it with asynctask task then!

Comment: @sadasidha but I'm doing everything in Javascript